# How to scroll an input component to the top of screen on onFocus in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I want to `scroll an input component to the top of screen on onFocus` in react-native.
Can anyone help me out?

react-native-cli: 2.0.1;
react-native: 0.60.5
[image]

Comment: why you need scroll to top?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to combine two rather advanced react native techniques, but I'm sure it can be done. I think there are 3 elements to your solution.

1. First of all you will need a `ref` to your input. By using a `ref` you can get a handle on the underlying control.
2. Once the `onFocus` event triggers of the text input, you can use that ref to `meaure` the `ref`. Measuring in react native is an async operations, but that should not be a problem in this sitation. https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation#measurecallback
3. The `measure` operation will return the position of the input inside its parent view, but also on the screen. With these values you can determine how much the ScrollView will need to scroll in order for the input to be at the top. https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview.html#scrollto

You can still run into problems if there isn't enough space to make scrolling possible. If that's the case you should take a look into `KeyboardAvoidingView`. That component was added react-native for that use case exactly. https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html

Comment: But, if there is no enough component below the input field to scroll to the top?

If there is enough component below the input field then your trick is working perfectly.

Comment: I extended the answer with some information about keyboardavoidingview